# Bus error (core dumped) при запуске почти любой утилиты в Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu

У меня перестали работать такие утилиты, как git, nginx, curl, node, npm. При попытке запустить их - одна и таже ошибка: "Bus error (core dumped)". Не могу понять причин, почему внезапно все "поломалось". Как исправить эту проблему?

Comment: Посмотрите dmesg (the kernel ring buffer) и /var/log/messages. Может увидите какую-то необычную диагностику

Comment: скороее всего, аппаратные проблемы с накопителем с системой

Comment: Ой, совсем забыл про основной -- /var/log/syslog

Comment: @avp в syslog ужасные сообщения, наподобие таких
Feb 21 23:03:24 laptop kernel: [ 9072.189213] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x800000 SErr 0x0 action 0x0

))

Comment: Диск накрылся Вариант, кабель. Поменять кабель, пропылесосить. Если не помогает, сменить диск, если не помогло, что маловероятно, менять контроллер (или целиком материнку).

Comment: Какие-то проблемы с дисковым контроллером. С таким сообщением можно уже в гугл идти. А можно сначала контакты шлейфа к диску  почистить (вдруг пропадет?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась только переустановкой Ubuntu